# SipVicious(100) incoming calls in my Sip Application

Tags: android, pjsip, pjsua2

I build my Android Sip application using pjsua library. I am using BSNL Wings service provider for sip account. I am receiving a call from 100, randomly at my phone which have no response from the other side even when answered.

I took the log, and came to know that these are sipvicious calls. How can I block such suspicious calls? Is this because of my apps poor security?

Below is some piece of logs

```
10:56:45.807   pjsua_core.c  .RX 406 bytes Request msg INVITE/cseq=1 (rdata0x94078014) from UDP 185.53.88.90:5104:
INVITE sip:100@25.66.144.5:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 127.0.0.1:5104;branch=z9hG4bK-935159066;rport
Content-Length: 0
From: "sipvicious"<sip:100@1.1.1.1>;tag=3839363132643836313363340131333034323431323430
Accept: application/sdp
User-Agent: friendly-scanner
To: "sipvicious"<sip:100@1.1.1.1>
Contact: sip:100@127.0.0.1:5104
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Call-ID: 470941564413303467070167
Max-Forwards: 70
--end msg--
SIP/2.0 100 Trying
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 127.0.0.1:5104;rport=5104;received=185.53.88.90;branch=z9hG4bK-935159066
Call-ID: 470941564413303467070167
From: "sipvicious" <sip:100@1.1.1.1>;tag=3839363132643836313363340131333034323431323430
To: "sipvicious" <sip:100@1.1.1.1>
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Content-Length:  0
--end msg--
======== Incoming call ======== 
handleMessage: INCOMING_CALL
10:56:45.830   pjsua_call.c !Answering call 0: code=180
10:56:45.830   pjsua_core.c  ....TX 499 bytes Response msg 180/INVITE/cseq=1 (tdta0x93618064) to UDP 185.53.88.90:5104:
SIP/2.0 180 Ringing
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 127.0.0.1:5104;rport=5104;received=185.53.88.90;branch=z9hG4bK-935159066
Call-ID: 470941564413303467070167
From: "sipvicious" <sip:100@1.1.1.1>;tag=3839363132643836313363340131333034323431323430
To: "sipvicious" <sip:100@1.1.1.1>;tag=af653679-5911-4a3d-bbe6-a83c8d50b2d2
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Contact: <sip:+919188991609@25.66.144.5:5060;ob>
Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
....
....
....
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 127.0.0.1:5104;rport=5104;received=185.53.88.90;branch=z9hG4bK-935159066
Call-ID: 470941564413303467070167
To: "sipvicious" <sip:100@1.1.1.1>;tag=af653679-5911-4a3d-bbe6-a83c8d50b2d2
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS
Contact: <sip:+919188991609@25.66.144.5:5060;ob>
Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length:   512
v=0
o=- 3779674023 3779674023 IN IP4 25.66.144.5
s=pjmedia
b=AS:84
t=0 0
a=X-nat:0
m=audio 4000 RTP/AVP 98 97 99 104 3 0 8 9 96
c=IN IP4 25.66.144.5
b=TIAS:64000
a=rtcp:4001 IN IP4 25.66.144.5
a=sendrecv
a=rtpmap:98 speex/16000
a=rtpmap:97 speex/8000
a=rtpmap:99 speex/32000
a=rtpmap:104 iLBC/8000
a=fmtp:104 mode=30
a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:96 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:96 0-16
a=ssrc:1119297598 cname:6bbc3fa2607711b7
--end msg--
BYE sip:100@127.0.0.1:5104 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 25.66.144.5:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPj149e8a65-dad5-4d32-a539-6b68b23a1e8f
Max-Forwards: 70
From: "sipvicious" <sip:100@1.1.1.1>;tag=af653679-5911-4a3d-bbe6-a83c8d50b2d2
To: "sipvicious" <sip:100@1.1.1.1>;tag=3839363132643836313363340131333034323431323430
Call-ID: 470941564413303467070167
CSeq: 30149 BYE
Content-Length:  0
--end msg--
```